# Is it possible to return spring webflux Flux<T> / Mono<T> for Graphql Queries?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, graphql-java

I need to implement a graphql query resolver for my reactive spring app.

here is my graphlq schema:

```
 type Post{
    id: String!
    title: String 
}

type Query {
    posts: [Post!]!
}
```

And my resolver looks like this:

```
 public Flux<Post> posts(){ ...}
```

I am using graphiql-spring-boot-starter 5.0.2 and graphql-java-tools 5.2.4

Comment: Just an update, I ended  up following this [example](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/tree/master/example-graphql-subscription) .  

I changed my method from  `public Flux<Post> posts(){ ...}`  to `public Publisher<Post> posts(){ ...}`.  The Publisher interface from org.reactivestreams.  Inside the method I returned a Flux.

Also, Had to change my query to a subscription.

Comment: Hi @lizom, i did similar implementation... but how did you call posts(), over http or ws..?

Comment: Hi @user1912935,  in my case, I was using graphql, so post() was actually a graphql subscription. So I would call it like this :
`
  subscription {
    posts {
      id
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.collectList().toFuture()` and then return `DataFetcher<CompletableFuture<T>>` if you are using graphql-java async

Comment: That is blocking.